# How to import something from one directory above in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-import

In my Django project, I have split models. The project directory kinda looks like this:

```
myproject/
    app1/
        validators.py
        views.py
        __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            model1.py
            model2.py
```

And of course, the models work properly thanks to this:

```
#myproject/app1/models/__init__.py:
from .model1 import Model1
from .model2 import Model2
```

Anyway, in my `model1.py` module, I want to import a validator from the `validators.py` module. But as you can see, its one directory above. How can I do this? Preferably, I would want a solution that works in all types of filesystems. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Why not use absolute modules, so `from app1.validators import SomeValidator`.

Comment: You can import this with `from ..validators import SomeValidator`, but that looks a bit "ugly"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is a bit ugly, but that doesn't matter tbh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two consecutive dots here, like:

```
# myproject/app1/models/__init__.py

from .model1 import Model1
from .model2 import Model2
from ..validators import SomeValidator
```

But perhaps it is better to use absolute imports here:

```
# myproject/app1/models/__init__.py

from .model1 import Model1
from .model2 import Model2
from app1.validators import SomeValidator
```